# Managing PostgreSQL database with the vim editor

Tags: postgresql, vim, editor, psql

Is it possible to manage my postgres database using VIM? Normally i use in my 
windows environment the cmd command line but i would like to find out if this is possible
and if it is could anyone provide a quick guide on how to do it?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim is not an IDE, and having a deep integration with things that are not directly related to text editing (like database management) within the editor is frowned upon.

That said, vi / Vim easily integrate with external tools, so if you have a handy command-line utility for managing Postgres, you can easily build your own mappings and commands to make frequently repeated tasks easier, mostly through `:!` or `:call system(...)`.

[Quick and dirty Postgres query](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_and_dirty_Postgres_query) on the Vim Tips Wiki provides a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [DBext](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) plugin. It contains functions/mappings/commands to enable Vim to access several databases, including postgres.

Comment: I was in a rush, simply added: 
nnoremap <F5> :%w ! psql <cr>
vnoremap <F5> :w ! psql <cr>
to my .vimrc and now F5 will execute anything I highlight, or if not highlighted the entire file. But yours is much better...